Inconsistent behaviour with pandas plot
why line chart is starting from size=2 and not size=1 like the bar chart?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'size': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'Yes': [1100.65, 1185.08, 338.30, 336.70, 58.61, 0.00],
    'No': [1700.32, 1380.81, 546.25, 722.00, 91.73, 139.32]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('size')
print(df)

# Plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

# Plot stacked bar chart on primary axis
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax, legend=False)

# Plot line chart on primary axis (same as bar chart)
df.plot(kind='line', ax=ax, legend=False)

plt.show()



The label 1 is located at data x-coordinate 0

The cause is @ifly6 comment, and the easiest solution is to not set size column to index.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

# Plot stacked bar chart on primary axis
df.plot(x='size', y=['Yes', 'No'], kind='bar', stacked=True, 
        ax=ax, legend=False, alpha=.5)

# Plot line chart on primary axis (same as bar chart)
df.plot(y=['Yes', 'No'], kind='line', ax=ax, legend=False, marker='o')

plt.show()



If I change size col to object it works as expected!

The issue with the location is that your bar plot is plotting the first bar at data x-coordinate 0. It then labels that as 1.
If you force the data coordinates to be shown, you can see this:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax, legend=False)

from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, ScalarFormatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())


Panda Kim gives a clear answer as to how you can get it not to do this and render it how you probably want. I also think the transparency and marker effects are nice touches. I guess this can be your answer as to why. (Another case of "computers do what you say, not what you mean"!)
